# Auto-memoizing Python interpreter for machine learning(Incpy alternative?)

Tags: python, caching

I am working on a machine learning project in python and many times I found myself rerun some algorithm with different tweaks each time(changing few parameters, different normalization, some extra feature engineering, etc). Each time most computation is similar except a few steps. I can, of course, save some immediate states on disk and load it next time instead of the computing the same thing over and over again.

The thing is that there are so many such immediate results that manually save them and keep a record of them would be a pain. I looked at some python decorator [here](https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/08/12/a-tip-for-the-impatient-simple-caching-with-python-pickle-and-decorators/) that can make things a bit easier. However, the problem with this implementation is, that it will always return the same result from the first time you called the function, even when your function has arguments and therefore should produce different results for different arguments. I really need to memorize the output of a function with different arguments.

I googled extensively on this topic and the closest thing that I found that is [IncPy](https://github.com/pgbovine/IncPy) by Philip Guo. IncPy (Incremental Python) is an enhanced Python interpreter that speeds up script execution times by automatically memoizing (caching) the results of long-running function calls and then re-using those results rather than re-computing, when safe to do so.

I really like the idea and think it will be very useful for data science and machine learning but the code is written nine years ago for python 2.6 and is no longer maintained.

So my question is that is there any other alternative automatical caching/memorizing techniques in python that can handle relatively large dataset?